# How to create a scatter plot with two colors per dot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot both the **ground-truth** and **my** classification simultaneously in matplotlib.

Currently, I only plot the groud-truth, after applying `tsne` on the feature space and adding the edges using the following code

```py
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
cols=['rgbkm'[lbl] for lbl in list(data.y.cpu().numpy() - 1)]

lc = LineCollection(X_embedded[out_dict['edges']],linewidth=0.05)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
plt.xlim(X_embedded[:,0].min(), X_embedded[:,0].max())
plt.ylim(X_embedded[:,1].min(), X_embedded[:,1].max())
plt.scatter(X_embedded[:,0],X_embedded[:,1], c=cols)
```

This gives the following plot:
[image]

While, I hope to somehow color each vertex in the following way:

[image]

Comment: You want every point to be exactly half red and half blue and in the same orientation as you show? Or does any part of the coloring depend on some variable?

Comment: ground-truth and my classification simultaneously, meaning I would like them to be set by some variable

Comment: And the variable would correspond to what? How much of the marker is red and how much is blue? The color of each half (i.e. alpha value, or different shade)?

Comment: no, I'll have for each vertex two classifications, e.g. 1-3 that will correspond to black/red for example, or 3-5 that will correspond to red/blue for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two approaches.

The dots of regular scatter plots can have an interior color and an edge color. `scatter` accepts an array for either one of them, but not for both. So, you could just iterate through all edge colors and plot them in a loop over the same plot.
Playing with linewidth might give help to visualize the true and the predicted colors together.

Matplotlib's `plot` function accepts marker [filling styles](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html), which have a possibility of being bicolored, either top-bottom or left-right. Per plot you can only give one type of style. So, for 5 colors, there are 25 combinations which can be drawn in a loop.

## Bonus points:

While looping through the colors, plot can generate legend labels with the corresponding bicolored dot.

Here is some code to illustrate the concepts:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np

N = 50

labels = ['ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', 'elk']  # suppose these are the labels for the prediction
colors = list('rgbkm') # a list of 5 colors
cols_true = np.repeat(range(5), N)  # suppose the first N have true color 0, the next N true color 1, ...
cols_pred = np.random.randint(0, 5, N * 5)  # as a demo, take a random number for each predicted color

# for x and y, suppose some 2D gaussian normal distribution around some centers,
#   this would make the 'true' colors nicely grouped 
x = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(cx, 2, N) for cx in [5, 9, 7, 2, 2]])
y = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(cy, 1.5, N) for cy in [2, 5, 9, 8, 3]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
for tc in range(5):
    for pc in range(5):
        mask = (cols_true == tc) & (cols_pred == pc)
        plt.plot(x[mask], y[mask], c=colors[tc], markerfacecoloralt=colors[pc],
                 marker='.', linestyle='', markeredgecolor='None',
                 markersize=15, fillstyle='left', markeredgewidth=0,
                 label=f'Tr: {labels[tc]} - Pr: {labels[pc]}')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, -0.1), fontsize=10, ncol=5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Wow, I thought it can't be done, and went with the edges scheme(as you also mentioned) before your post. Amazing