# Python Scatter Plot Edgecolors by Label

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically set the edgecolor of a datapoint. 
The facecolor can be set by using c=[array of numeric labels], but not so for edgecolors.

What im trying to achieve is a plot where the facecolor equals the predicted label of an algorithm for an instance, and the edgecolor equals the true label of that instance. 
This way, i could visually compare the results (important for further work).

Any suggestions? This is my code so far:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], c=y_train)
axs[0, 0].set_title('org.Data with true labels')
axs[0, 1].scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], c=y_pred)
axs[0, 1].set_title('org.Data with LOF labels')
axs[1, 0].scatter(data_PCA[:,0],data_PCA[:,1], c=y_pred)
axs[1, 0].set_title("PCAplt, labels LOF: org.Data")
axs[1, 1].scatter(data_PCA[:,0],data_PCA[:,1], c=y_pred_PCA)
axs[1, 1].set_title('PCA.plt, labels LOF: PCA')
```

which gives me the following plot

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you!

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810599/how-to-create-a-scatter-plot-with-two-colors-per-dot/59831737#59831737) about how to create a bicolored scatter plot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer comes after laying stuff to rest for some time. I found a solution and wanted to share in case anyone ever needs this:

In short: I precomputed a list of "true label colors" using a very simple list comprehension, and used another list of length 2 with the same colors for the facecolors.

The code:

```
colors = ["green","red"]
true_labels_color_encoded = ["red" if label == 1 else "green" for label in y_train]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], c=y_train, cmap=ListedColormap(colors), edgecolors=true_labels_color_encoded)
axs[0, 0].set_title('org.Data with true labels')
axs[0, 1].scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], c=y_pred,cmap=ListedColormap(colors),edgecolors=true_labels_color_encoded)
axs[0, 1].set_title('org.Data with LOF labels')
axs[1, 0].scatter(data_PCA[:,0],data_PCA[:,1], c=y_pred,cmap=ListedColormap(colors),edgecolors=true_labels_color_encoded)
axs[1, 0].set_title("PCAplt, labels LOF: org.Data")
axs[1, 1].scatter(data_PCA[:,0],data_PCA[:,1], c=y_pred_PCA,cmap=ListedColormap(colors),edgecolors=true_labels_color_encoded)
axs[1, 1].set_title('PCA.plt, labels LOF: PCA')
```

so true_labels_color_encoded looks something like = ["red","green","green","green"]
(note: in my case, a label in y_train = 1 means anomaly, and 0 means normal)

which gives me the following plot:

[See my plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y84HR.png)

I got even better results using other reduction techniques like ISOMAP or t-SNE.