# Set two colors for a point of a matplotlib-scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

So Realising that this may not possible. What I want to do, looks something like this:

```
point_x = [1]
point_y = [1]

col1 =    ['blue']
col2 =    ['red']

plt.scatter(point_x,point_y, c=col1,marker='o')
plt.scatter(point_x,point_y, c=col2,marker=donut?)
```

This would represent one point, where a portion of the (let's say)  sphere, is color1, and a portion of (probably) a donut around the center of sphere, is color2.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: You can use edge color and line width for the border: `plt.scatter(point_x, point_y, marker='o', s=1000, lw=2, ec='blue', c='red')`.

Comment: See also [How to create a scatter plot with two colors per dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810599/how-to-create-a-scatter-plot-with-two-colors-per-dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe specifiying the point size s would help

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

point_x = 1
point_y = 1

col1 = ['blue']
col2 = ['red']

plt.scatter(point_x, point_y, c=col1, marker='o', s=1000)
plt.scatter(point_x, point_y, c=col2, marker='o', s=500)
plt.show()
```

output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. seems you are "overplotting" above the outter circle